# Can an ADS-B In/Out equipped aircraft increase ground station coverage?

Tags: ads-b

Suppose a ground station can detect aircraft in a 200 km radius with ADS-B In.
There is a plane A at 180 km, and another one B at 250 km, both equipped with ADS-B In/Out.

If ground station receives A, and A receives B: Can B information go to ground station using A as a repeater?